# Python Recursive Depth First Search Performance Tips (Is Cython an option?)

Tags: python, performance, optimization, graph, cython

I have a project that relies on finding all cycles in a graph that pass through a vertex at most k times. Naturally, I'm sticking with the case of k=1 for the sake of development right now. I've come to the conclusion that this algorithm as a depth first search is at worst O((kn)^(kn)) for a complete graph, but I rarely approach this upper bound in the context of the problem, so I would still like to give this approach a try.

I've implemented the following as a part of the project to achieve this end:

```
class Graph(object):

...

def path_is_valid(self, current_path):
    """
    :param current_path:
    :return: Boolean indicating a whether the given path is valid
    """
    length = len(current_path)
    if length < 3:
        # The path is too short
        return False

    # Passes through vertex twice... sketchy for general case
    if len(set(current_path)) != len(current_path):
        return False

    # The idea here is take a moving window of width three along the path
    # and see if it's contained entirely in a polygon.
    arc_triplets = (current_path[i:i+3] for i in xrange(length-2))
    for triplet in arc_triplets:
        for face in self.non_fourgons:
            if set(triplet) <= set(face):
                return False

    # This is all kinds of unclear when looking at. There is an edge case
    # pertaining to the beginning and end of a path existing inside of a
    # polygon. The previous filter will not catch this, so we cycle the path
    # and recheck moving window filter.
    path_copy = list(current_path)
    for i in xrange(length):
        path_copy = path_copy[1:] + path_copy[:1]  # wtf
        arc_triplets = (path_copy[i:i+3] for i in xrange(length-2))
        for triplet in arc_triplets:
            for face in self.non_fourgons:
                if set(triplet) <= set(face):
                    return False

    return True

def cycle_dfs(self, current_node,  start_node,  graph, current_path):
    """

    :param current_node:
    :param start_node:
    :param graph:
    :param current_path:
    :return:
    """
    if len(current_path) >= 3:
        last_three_vertices = current_path[-3:]
        previous_three_faces = [set(self.faces_containing_arcs[vertex])
                                for vertex in last_three_vertices]
        intersection_all = set.intersection(*previous_three_faces)
        if len(intersection_all) == 2:
            return []

    if current_node == start_node:
        if self.path_is_valid(current_path):
            return [tuple(shift(list(current_path)))]
        else:
            return []

    else:
        loops = []
        for adjacent_node in set(graph[current_node]):
            current_path.append(adjacent_node)
            graph[current_node].remove(adjacent_node)
            graph[adjacent_node].remove(current_node)
            loops += list(self.cycle_dfs(adjacent_node, start_node,
                                         graph, current_path))
            graph[current_node].append(adjacent_node)
            graph[adjacent_node].append(current_node)
            current_path.pop()
        return loops
```

`path_is_valid()` aims to cut down on the number of paths produced by the depth first search as they are found, based upon filtering criteria that are specific to the problem. I tried to explain the purpose of each one reasonably, but everything is clearer in one's own head; I'd be happy to improve the comments if needed.

I'm open to any and all suggestions to improve performance, since, as the profile below shows, this is what is taking all my time.

Also, I'm about to turn to Cython, but my code heavily relies on Python objects and I don't know if that's a smart move. Can anyone shed some light as to whether or not this route is even beneficial with this many native Python data structures involved? I can't seem to find much information on this and any help would be appreciated.

Since I know people will ask, I have profiled my entire project and this is the source of the problem:

```
   311         1     18668669 18668669.0     99.6              cycles = self.graph.find_cycles()
```

Here's the line-profiled output of the `self.graph.find_cycles()` and `self.path_is_valid()`:

```
Function: cycle_dfs at line 106
Total time: 11.9584 s 

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
   106                                               def cycle_dfs(self, current_node,  start_node,  graph, current_path):
   107                                                   """
   108                                                   Naive depth first search applied to the pseudo-dual graph of the
   109                                                   reference curve. This sucker is terribly inefficient. More to come.
   110                                                   :param current_node:
   111                                                   :param start_node:
   112                                                   :param graph:
   113                                                   :param current_path:
   114                                                   :return:
   115                                                   """
   116    437035       363181      0.8      3.6          if len(current_path) >= 3:
   117    436508       365213      0.8      3.7              last_three_vertices = current_path[-3:]
   118    436508       321115      0.7      3.2              previous_three_faces = [set(self.faces_containing_arcs[vertex])
   119   1746032      1894481      1.1     18.9                                      for vertex in last_three_vertices]
   120    436508       539400      1.2      5.4              intersection_all = set.intersection(*previous_three_faces)
   121    436508       368725      0.8      3.7              if len(intersection_all) == 2:
   122                                                           return []
   123                                           
   124    437035       340937      0.8      3.4          if current_node == start_node:
   125     34848      1100071     31.6     11.0              if self.path_is_valid(current_path):
   126       486         3400      7.0      0.0                  return [tuple(shift(list(current_path)))]
   127                                                       else:
   128     34362        27920      0.8      0.3                  return []
   129                                           
   130                                                   else:
   131    402187       299968      0.7      3.0              loops = []
   132    839160       842350      1.0      8.4              for adjacent_node in set(graph[current_node]):
   133    436973       388646      0.9      3.9                  current_path.append(adjacent_node)
   134    436973       438763      1.0      4.4                  graph[current_node].remove(adjacent_node)
   135    436973       440220      1.0      4.4                  graph[adjacent_node].remove(current_node)
   136    436973       377422      0.9      3.8                  loops += list(self.cycle_dfs(adjacent_node, start_node,
   137    436973       379207      0.9      3.8                                               graph, current_path))
   138    436973       422298      1.0      4.2                  graph[current_node].append(adjacent_node)
   139    436973       388651      0.9      3.9                  graph[adjacent_node].append(current_node)
   140    436973       412489      0.9      4.1                  current_path.pop()
   141    402187       285471      0.7      2.9              return loops

Function: path_is_valid at line 65
Total time: 1.6726 s

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
65                                               def path_is_valid(self, current_path):
66                                                   """
67                                                   Aims to implicitly filter during dfs to decrease output size. Observe
68                                                   that more complex filters are applied further along in the function.
69                                                   We'd rather do less work to show the path is invalid rather than more,
70                                                   so filters are applied in order of increasing complexity.
71                                                   :param current_path:
72                                                   :return: Boolean indicating a whether the given path is valid
73                                                   """
74     34848        36728      1.1      2.2          length = len(current_path)
75     34848        33627      1.0      2.0          if length < 3:
76                                                       # The path is too short
77        99           92      0.9      0.0              return False
78                                           
79                                                   # Passes through arcs twice... Sketchy for later.
80     34749        89536      2.6      5.4          if len(set(current_path)) != len(current_path):
81     31708        30402      1.0      1.8              return False
82                                           
83                                                   # The idea here is take a moving window of width three along the path
84                                                   # and see if it's contained entirely in a polygon.
85      3041         6287      2.1      0.4          arc_triplets = (current_path[i:i+3] for i in xrange(length-2))
86     20211        33255      1.6      2.0          for triplet in arc_triplets:
87     73574        70670      1.0      4.2              for face in self.non_fourgons:
88     56404        94019      1.7      5.6                  if set(triplet) <= set(face):
89      2477         2484      1.0      0.1                      return False
90                                           
91                                                   # This is all kinds of unclear when looking at. There is an edge case
92                                                   # pertaining to the beginning and end of a path existing inside of a
93                                                   # polygon. The previous filter will not catch this, so we cycle the path
94                                                   # a reasonable amount and recheck moving window filter.
95       564          895      1.6      0.1          path_copy = list(current_path)
96      8028         7771      1.0      0.5          for i in xrange(length):
97      7542        14199      1.9      0.8              path_copy = path_copy[1:] + path_copy[:1]  # wtf
98      7542        11867      1.6      0.7              arc_triplets = (path_copy[i:i+3] for i in xrange(length-2))
99    125609       199100      1.6     11.9              for triplet in arc_triplets:
100    472421       458030      1.0     27.4                  for face in self.non_fourgons:
101    354354       583106      1.6     34.9                      if set(triplet) <= set(face):
102        78           83      1.1      0.0                          return False
103                                           
104       486          448      0.9      0.0          return True
```

Thanks!

EDIT: Well, after a lot of merciless profiling, I was able to bring the run time down from 12 seconds to ~1.5.

I changed this portion of `cycle_dfs()`

```
    last_three_vertices = current_path[-3:]
    previous_three_faces = [set(self.faces_containing_arcs[vertex])
                            for vertex in last_three_vertices]
    intersection_all = set.intersection(*previous_three_faces)
    if len(intersection_all) == 2: ...
```

to this:

```
        # Count the number of times each face appears by incrementing values
        # of face_id's
        containing_faces = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
        for face in (self.faces_containing_arcs[v]
                     for v in current_path[-3:]):
            for f in face:
                containing_faces[f] += 1
        # If there's any face_id f that has a value of three, that means that
        # there is one face that all three arcs bound. This is a trivial path
        # so we discard it.
        if 3 in containing_faces.values(): ...
```

This was motivated by another post I saw benchmarking Python dictionary assignment; turns out assigning and editing values in a dict is a tiny bit slower than adding integers (which still blows my mind). Along with the two additions to `self.path_is_valid()`, I squeaked out a 12x speedup. However, further suggestions would be appreciated since better performance overall will only make harder problems easier as the input complexity grows.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend two optimizations for `path_is_valid`. Of course, your main problem is in `cycle_dfs`, and you probably just need a better algorithm.

1) Avoid creating extra data structures:

```
 for i in xrange(length-2):
   for face in self.non_fourgons:
      if (path[i] in face && path[i+1] in face && path[i+2] in face):
        return False
```

2) Create a dictionary mapping points to the non_fourgons they are members of:

```
 for i in xrange(length-2):
   for face in self.non_fourgons[ path[i] ]:
      if (path[i+1] in face && path[i+2] in face):
        return False
```

The expression `self.non_fourgons[ p ]` should return a list of the non-fourgons
which contain `p` as a member. This reduces the number of polygons you have to check.

Comment: Awesome thank you! I was looking for less terrible ways to do that bit and I couldn't think of much off hand. I'll add them in now.

Comment: Those two optimizations brought a 60% speed up! Down to 4 seconds from 12! You're the man!